# Configuration Nested Entity using DIH in SOLR

Tags: solr, configuration, nested, structure, document

I wanna create nested entity with DIH using SOLR 6.x

i read 
[Defining nested entities in Solr Data Import Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24920305/defining-nested-entities-in-solr-data-import-handler)

and jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5147

what i did

> Schema.xml

```
<fields>
<field name="variantList" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"    />
<field name="variantList.variants" type="string" multiValued="false" required="false"/>
<field name="variantList.stockMinimum" type="int" multiValued="false" required="false"/>
<field name="variantList.stockOnHand" type="int" multiValued="false" required="false"/>
<field name="variantList.stockVariantId" type="long" multiValued="false" required="false"/>
</fields>
```

> data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource /> 
  <document>
    <entity name="PARENT" rootEntity='true' query="*" >
     <field column="ID" name="id" />
     <field column="BRAND_ID" name="brandId" />
     <field column="PRODUCT_ID" name="productId" />
     <field column="MERCHANT_PRODUCT_ID" name="merchantProductId" />
     <field column="MERCHANT_ID" name="merchantId" />
     <field column="SALES_REGION" name="salesRegion" />
     <field column="LOCAL_DIRECT_DELIVERY" name="localDirectDelivery" />
     <field column="NORMAL_SELLINGPRICE" name="normalSellingPrice" />
     <field column="NEW_PRODUCT" name="newProduct" />
     <field column="BEST_SELLER" name="bestSeller" />
     <field column="CATEGORY1_ID" name="category1Id" />
     <field column="CATEGORY2_ID" name="category2Id" />
     <field column="CATEGORY3_ID" name="category3Id" />
     <field column="CATEGORY4_ID" name="category4Id" />
     <field column="DISPLAY_IMAGE_PATH" name="displayImagePath" />
     <field column="MERCHANT_NAME" name="merchantName" />
     <field column="PRODUCT_NAME" name="productName" />
     <field column="CATEGORY1_NAME" name="category1Name" />
     <field column="CATEGORY2_NAME" name="category2Name" />
     <field column="CATEGORY3_NAME" name="category3Name" />
     <field column="CATEGORY4_NAME" name="category4Name" />





        <entity name="variantList" child="true" query="select VARIANT , STOCK_MINIMUM , STOCK_ONHAND , ID from SIF_MERCHANT_CATALOG_VARIANT 
                                                    where MERCHANT_CATALOG_ID = '${PARENT.ID}'">
                <field column="VARIANT" name="variantList.variants_s" />
                <field column="STOCK_MINIMUM" name="variantList.stockMinimum" />
                <field column="STOCK_ONHAND" name="variantList.stockOnHand" />
                <field column="ID" name="variantList.stockVariantId" />
            </entity>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

result that i want

```
<doc parent_1/>
  <doc child_1/>
  <doc child_1/>
<doc parent_2/>
  <doc child_1/>
```

and what i get

```
<doc child_1/>
<doc child_1/>
<doc parent_1/>
<doc child_2/>
<doc parent_2/>
```

and i see aheryan's anwers , it should be right , i can use **child=true**

am i miss something ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child docs are returned together with parent docs if you just do a general query. As a flat list. So, that's probably what you are seeing.

The easiest way to check whether you got nested documents is to look at the value of the _root_ field, as the value will be the same for all documents in the parent/child hierarchy block.

You could also search for parent documents only and use [Child Document Transformer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Transforming+Result+Documents#TransformingResultDocuments-[child]-ChildDocTransformerFactory) to list its children.

Comment: ooh thank you ! i miss that child document transformer , thank you !