# Import nested entities in Solr DIH

Tags: solr

I need configure nested entities which are imported via DIH. Between user and address is one to many cardinality (user has many addresses).

This is our import definition in data-config.xml

```
<document>
    <entity name="user" query="...">
           <field column="id" name="id" />
           <field column="code" name="code" />
        // next fields of user

        <entity name="address" child="true" query="..." where="user_id=user.id">
           <field column="id" name="id" />
           <field column="city" name="city" />
           // ... next fields of address
        </entity>
    </entity>
</document>
```

and schema.xml configuration like this:

```
// user fields
<field name="id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="code" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
// ...

// address fields
<field name="address" type="string" indexed="true" multiValued="true"  stored="true" />
<field name="address.id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="address.city" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />
// ...
```

This solution cause that no address object is imported. Thank you for any advice.

EDIT:
I also found many warning logs
`Error creating document : SolrInputDocument(fields: [user_id=122, ... _version_=1671840418228076544,&#8203; _root_=00924553002],&#8203; children: [SolrInputDocument(fields: [address_id=1,&#8203; _root_=00924553002,&#8203; _version_=1671840418228076544]),&#8203; SolrInputDocument(fields: [address_id=20,&#8203; _root_=00924553002,&#8203; _version_=1671840418228076544])])`

EDIT 2:
Default logs in application hide error. I checked server logs on machine, and I found this error:  `org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: [doc=null] missing required field: code at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:245)`

In schema.xml I have this field set as identifier of user, but children doesn't have this field. Then I tried add code field as alias for ID, and I found another error which tell there is missing value in required fields which are used in parent object (user). This conditions were applied also on nested objects. So I tried also remove these condition from these fields. After this import ran, but when I execute select, all objects are on same level. Solr imported it as flat.

This is expected select result:

```
{
  "reponse": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "tsdx242-234",
      "first_name": "Michael",
      "last_name": "Sprox",
      "addresses": [
        {
          "id": 44,
          "city": "Paris",
          "street": "Champs-Elysees"
        },
        {
          "id": 24,
          "city": "Budapest",
          "street": "Akácfa utca"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "code": "xx45982-114",
      "first_name": "Petra",
      "last_name": "Jurka",
      "addresses": [
        {
          "id": 31,
          "city": "Vienna",
          "street": "Karlsplatz"
        },
        {
          "id": 44,
          "city": "Paris",
          "street": "Champs-Elysees"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But it gives this, mixed users and addresses in one lovel:

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "id": 44,
      "city": "Paris",
      "street": "Champs-Elysees"
    },
    {
      "id": 24,
      "city": "Budapest",
      "street": "Akácfa utca"
    },
    {
      "id": 31,
      "city": "Vienna",
      "street": "Karlsplatz"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "tsdx242-234",
      "first_name": "Michael",
      "last_name": "Sprox"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "code": "xx45982-114",
      "first_name": "Petra",
      "last_name": "Jurka"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24920305/defining-nested-entities-in-solr-data-import-handler

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838090/configuration-nested-entity-using-dih-in-solr

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti not helps, but I found something in logs, so I edited question. Check it please.

Comment: hey , you can find exact error in ..\solr-7.6.0\server\logs\solr.log , can you plz edit your question with that error log.

Comment: @MansiJoshi I updated question with error from server log.

Comment: @Denis Stephanov  your error shows that `code` fields is require in your schema and when solr perform indexing it missing from database. so if that field is not required then simple set `required="false"`. hope this help!!

Comment: @MansiJoshi yes, I edited it and remove required condition where it failed, but problem is that after this, solr import data in flat model. It didn't create array field with nested objects as I expected

Comment: @Denis Stephanov can you plz share your current output and expected output.

Comment: @MansiJoshi I updated question check it please

Comment: @Denis Stephanov https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/indexing-nested-documents.html  can you check `Schema Configuration` from this link for `root` fields and other some ponits.

Comment: @MansiJoshi yes I have it

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite it to someting like this

```
<document>
        <entity name="user" query="...">
               <field column="id" name="id" />
            // next fields of user
    
            <entity name="second_entity_name" pk="user_id" query="SELECT ... FROM where user_id = '${user.id}'" >
               <field column="id" name="id" />
               <field column="city" name="city" />
               // ... next fields of address
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
```

Comment: Hi, this no helped, but I found some warning logs, so I added it into question.

Comment: You can expand logs to see more detailed info, it might be that mappings type is wrongly set

Comment: Check EDIT 2 please. I found possible reason of error.

Comment: Try to do mapping slowly by mapping one field to one and set require to false. Looks like you have wrong mapping

Comment: I tried and solr imported data but wrong. Check edit 2, import pass but data were imported in flat model, so there were not hierarchy and all objects were on same level